# finding saddle point in 2d matrix

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, saddle

I’m trying to find the saddle point of a 2d Matrix and refer back to the Matrix by using a pointer, but my code isn’t executing as intended.

here is my code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, m, i, j;
    int small, smallcol, large, largerow;

    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);  // n is row, m is column
    int a[n][m];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    int* p[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        p[i] = a[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        small = *p[I];
        smallcol = 0;
        ;
        for (j = 1; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (*(p[i] + j) > small)
            {
                small = *(p[i] + j);
            }
        }
        large = *(p[0] + smallcol);
        largerow = 0;
        for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (*(p[j] + smallcol) > large)
            {
                large = *(p[j] + smallcol);
                largerow = j;
            }
        }

        if (i == largerow)
        {
            printf("%d", *(p[i] + smallcol));
        }
        if (i != largerow)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

this picture shows the input (3x3 matrix) and the output should have been blank instead of 8 since there is no saddle point in the matrix. I'm not sure what the problem with my code is

Edit: I ran into a new problem. One of the test cases has the input as:

(3x4) matrix, *with an extraneous `-1` and `-5` in the last column on the right*:

Input:

```
-1 -2 -1  3 -1
-3 -5  2  3 -5
 0  0  0  1
```

Output: `-2`

Expected output should be `0`.

In this test case, the `-1` and `-5` are extra inputs that exceed the number of columns. They should be considered as null, but in this case they aren’t.

Comment: `[I]` looks suspicious. Shouldn't it be `[i]`?

Comment: I made a mistake pasting the code, it's supposed to be [I], sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What is the definition of the saddle point in this context? The only thing is given is code that produces incorrect output

Comment: Saddle point is a number that is the minimum in its row and maximum in its column

Comment: Ok. What about points on the boundaries of the matrix?

Comment: What do you mean by those points ?

Comment: You should have posted the input as text rather than a picture.

Comment: I didn't know what a "saddle point" is. For anyone else wondering, see here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/saddle-point-matrix/amp/ and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors are here:

```
      if (*(p[i] + j) > small)
        {
```

You meant `<` rather than `>`, and forgot to store the column index; correct:

```
      if (*(p[i] + j) < small)    // or simply if (a[i][j] < small)
      {   smallcol = j,
```

Comment: @StevenYelnats, please thank Armali by 1. upvoting their answer using the up arrow to the left of their answer (that gives them 10 points), 2. marking their answer as the correct answer (if it solves your problem), by clicking the green checkmark next to their answer (that gives them 15 more points, and it gives you 2 points). "Thanks" is best given in the form of upvotes and answers marked as correct.